# Make Shuffle 3 different associated arrays so that they show the correct associated data

Tags: arrays, random, swiftui

I have this music quiz app, where the user plays a song from a URL, with the following questions and alternatives. I would like to randomize the order of the questions (musicQ), but at the same time have the correct a, b and c alternatives shown. In other words, I need to randomize these in the same order. Is there any ideas on how? .shuffled does not work for my porpuse.

In the View I show the arrays like this: `Text(musicQ[counter])` with a button to get next question: `Button { self.counter += 1 } label: { Text("Next") }`

```
@State private var counter = 0
@State private var spotifyURL =
    [
        "https://open.spotify.com/track/79nMHWTfds6KJu5zWQbQ4n?si=83cba55e1f994307", "https://open.spotify.com/track/6wU7z4Po2ieZ9S4cXbGLNr?si=432314b6fb0a442d", "https://open.spotify.com/track/4XoTO4jKYPdvGyfj0cUqVP?si=001de90e186348ca"
    ]
    @State private var musicQ =
    [
        "Artitst?", "From?", "Producer?"
    ]
    @State private var a =
    [
        "Corinne Bailey Rae", "Flus", "MADZI"
    ]
    @State private var b =
    [
        "Etta Jones", "19", "Brooks"
    ]
    @State private var c =
    [
        "Imelda May", "Rykter", "JOXION"
    ]
´´´
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `struct` to hold the answers in the order you want, then randomize the array of that `struct`. You can use another `struct` for each answer.

```
struct Answer {
    let artist: String
    let from: String
    let producer: String

    init(_ artist: String, _ from: String, _ producer: String) {
        self.artist = artist
        self.from = from
        self.producer = producer
    }
}

struct Question: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()

    let url: String
    let answerA: Answer
    let answerB: Answer
    let answerC: Answer
}

let questions: [Question] = [
    Question(
        url: "https://open.spotify.com/track/whatever",
        answerA: Answer("Corinne Bailey Rae", "Flus", "MADZI"),
        answerB: Answer("Etta Jones", "19", "Brooks"),
        answerC: Answer("Imelda May", "Rykter", "JOXION")
    ),

    Question(
        url: "https://open.spotify.com/track/secondTrack",
        answerA: Answer("Artist 1", "writer 1", "producer 1"),
        answerB: Answer("Artist 2", "writer 2", "producer 2"),
        answerC: Answer("Artist 3", "writer 3", "producer 3")
    )
]


let shuffledQuestions = questions.shuffled()
```

In the view:

```
    let question = shuffledQuestions[counter]

    Text(question.url)

    HStack {
        Text(question.answerA.artist)
        Text(question.answerA.from)
        Text(question.answerA.producer)
    }

    HStack {
        Text(question.answerB.artist)
        Text(question.answerB.from)
        Text(question.answerB.producer)
    }

    HStack {
        Text(question.answerC.artist)
        Text(question.answerC.from)
        Text(question.answerC.producer)
    }
}
```